# Looking for mobile web app map control that can handle layer redraw with good performance

Tags: leaflet, openlayers, google-maps, google-maps-api, ext-js

I would like to develop mobile web app to track GPS coordinates in real time (refresh every 10 seconds) from Geoserver.

Currently I have desktop site I wrote in ExtJS 4 and it works pretty well (Openlayers + GeoJson from WFS) - the layer redraws are not noticeable and it gives a feeling that the points are moving (because there are no flickering when layer redraw).

I've tried doing the same using sencha touch 2 (found leaflet and Openlayers plugins on Github) . here is what I achieved thus far:

1. Tried Google map v3 API - the map renders fast but when drawing the geojson layer or kml layer , in order to update I need to delete the previous features and redraw which cause all the markers to flicker.
2. Openlayers - The map renders very slow when panning / zooming.
3. Leaflet - Also , the map renders very slow (and sometimes idle...) when trying to pan fast or zoom multiple times.

At this point I'm stuck with a nice UI but poor performance map control (or maybe I'm not using the Google API correctly)

This is how I implemented it using Google API:

```
var gMap = Ext.getCmp('map').getMap();
georssLayer.setMap(null);
georssLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
   url: 'http://apps.utilis.co.il/geoserver2/wms/reflect?layers=ClearcutCB:DeviceInfo& format=rss&rnd=' + Math.random()});
georssLayer.setMap(gMap);
```

Will be more than happy having your advise on this one.

Comment: possible tip: use the kml/geojson in fusion tables - the google servers will render it faster than geoserver.

Comment: can you direct me to example ?

Comment: @Mapperz - Do you suggest I'll insert the GPS coords in real time to fusion tables and also read them in real time from there?